# What does "8+(int)" in Yii Tag Model mean?

Tags: php, yii, tags

I know what does (int) mean but this's the first time i see (int) being used like this and i have no idea what does it mean. It's from this piece of code in Tag model.

```
public function findTagWeights($limit=20)
    {
        $models=$this->findAll(array(
            'order'=>'frequency DESC',
            'limit'=>$limit,
        ));

        $total=0;
        foreach($models as $model)
            $total+=$model->frequency;

        $tags=array();
        if($total>0)
        {
            foreach($models as $model)
                $tags[$model->name]=8+(int)(16*$model->frequency/($total+10));
            ksort($tags);
        }
        return $tags;
    }
```

I'm confused because of this part

```
8+(int)(16*$model->frequency/($total+10))
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only means  result of `(16*$model->frequency/($total+10))` should be cast as `int` before its added to `8`, nothing more nothing less.

Here is an example to make it clear

```
echo 8 + (int)(2.5+2);   // 12 instead of 12.5
```

This removes any possible fractions and returns an integer in every case.

Comment: Ah!!! Thank you~ So it's like that, i see. I have to wait for a few minutes to accept answer, so really thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

The `(int)` [casts](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the number, after it, to an integer.

```
8 + (int)(16 * $model->frequency / ($total + 10));
```

It is the same as:

```
8 + intval(16 * $model->frequency / ($total + 10));
```